# Using CASE in MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I've done some research on the site, and doesn't appear this exact question is a duplicate, so here goes...

I'm creating a trigger in MySQL (after insert) with the goal to set two values (val1, val2) depending on the value of a third field (val3). I'm using CASE because there are only 5 possible values for val3. Problem is that my syntax is throwing errors in MySQL workbench, specifically: "When is not a valid input at this position".

Based on documentation I've read, CASE is valid to use in MySQL triggers, so it must be my syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Also, in case anyone asks, I also tried using IF/IFELSE, but also got errors. Either one (IF, CASE) works for me...

Here's the code I have now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trig1` 
AFTER INSERT ON `tbl`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
CASE    
WHEN NEW.val3 = 1 THEN
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = 0,
    val2 = 1;
WHEN NEW.val3 = 2 THEN
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = 0.25,
    val2 = 0.75;
WHEN NEW.val3 = 3 THEN
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = 0.5,
    val2 = 0.5;
WHEN NEW.val3 = 4 THEN
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = 0.75,
    val2 = 0.25;
WHEN NEW.val3 = 5 THEN
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = 1,
    val2 = 0;
END CASE;
END;
```

Comment: `I also tried using IF/IFELSE, but also got errors. Either one (IF, CASE) works for me` => What error did you get.

Comment: "ELSEIF is not a valid input at this position"

Code looked something like:

CREATE TRIGGER `trig1` 
AFTER INSERT ON `tbl`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
IF (NEW.val3 = 1) THEN
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = 0,
    val2 = 1;
ELSEIF (NEW.val3 = 2) THEN
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = 0.25,
    val2 = 0.75;
ELSE
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = 0.5,
    val2 = 0.5;
END IF;
END;

Comment: If you are creating a trigger on ´tbl´, you can't update ´tbl´ from the trigger. If you want to update the table, create a trigger ´BEFORE INSERT´ and use ´NEW.field = newValue´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Update

I simplified the update to derive `val1` and `val2` based on `val3` so you don't need `case` or `if/else` anymore

```
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = (NEW.val3-1)/4,
    val2 = 1-((NEW.val3-1)/4);
```

> Previous Query

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trig1` 
AFTER INSERT ON `tbl`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN       
    UPDATE `tbl`
    SET val3 = NEW.val3,
    val1 = case NEW.val3 when 1 then 0 when 2 then 0.25 
        when 3 then 0.5 when 4 then 0.75 when 5 then 1 end,
    val2 = case NEW.val3 when 1 then 1 when 2 then 0.75 
        when 3 then 0.5 when 4 then 0.25 when 5 then 0 end
    ;
END;
```

Comment: Fantastic, much appreciated! Tried both, and they both work great. Thanks for the ultra-quick response.